# Вставить выражение в строку на определенное место

Tags: python, python-3.x

Собираю необходимые мне ссылки и столкнулся с проблемой.
Все ссылки без указания страницы, пример: `/nintendo-4927/nintendo-igry-4929?reff=menu_main`.
Как я могу в Python'е поработать со строкой, чтобы получилось `/nintendo-4927/nintendo-igry-4929?page=2&reff=menu_main`.
Разница в `page=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В get-запросах порядок параметров не важен. Добавляйте `&page=2` в конец строки.

Например, пусть ссылка хранится в переменной `link`

```py
link = '/nintendo-4927/nintendo-igry-4929?reff=menu_main'
link += '&page=2'
# результат: /nintendo-4927/nintendo-igry-4929?reff=menu_main&page=2
```

Comment: О, я совсем забыл про это.
Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @AlexandrKiselev Вместо спасибо надо отметить ответ как решение